# String is not getting returned by return<string> and therefore i am unable to use that string in another class

Tags: java, android, string, return

i am having a little issue here. I have a `public String`and a `return`at the end. return should get value back so i can use it in another class, but this is not happening. After calling that string from another class i want to setText to a textfield. 
I have a feeling like i am missing something inside the for loop, but i can see what? any hint and answers kindly appreciated :)

```
public String Question (String quesion)
    {
        RandomMathQuestionGenerator questionGenerator = new RandomMathQuestionGenerator();
        List<Question> randomQuestions = questionGenerator.getGeneratedRandomQuestions();
        for (Question question : randomQuestions) 
        {
            System.out.println(question);//prints questions
        }
        return quesion;
    }
```

in another class i have

```
String ArithmeticQuestion = null;
    ArithmeticQuestion = question.Question(ArithmeticQuestion);

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.displayBox);
    editText.setText(ArithmeticQuestion);
```

Comment: why pass the question? you also never set "quesion" in your Question function

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to do but your Question method (btw you should check out this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) just returns the input parameter quesion which is null when called from you other class.

Comment: The way you do it, you pass in ArithmeticQuestion = null you get back your ArithmeticQuestion which is of course null.

Comment: Your variable/method/class naming conventions (or lack of conventions) make this code snippet MUCH harder to read than it should be...

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin when i however get rid of the ArithmeticQuestion initialization of null, i get underlined ArithmeticQuestion in "question.Question(ArithmeticQuestion)" saying that "ArithmeticQuestion may not have been initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing null to Question (methods and variables should start with lowercase in Java btw), Question is returning that null, and you're then assigning null back to ArithmeticQuestion. That's probably not what you want to do.

If you want to pass back a random question from the List, you could do something like this:

```
public String Question (String quesion)
{
    RandomMathQuestionGenerator questionGenerator = new RandomMathQuestionGenerator();
    List<Question> randomQuestions = questionGenerator.getGeneratedRandomQuestions();
    for (Question question : randomQuestions) 
    {
        System.out.println(question);//prints questions
    }
    Random random = new java.util.Random();
    return randomQuestions.get(random.nextInt(randomQuestions.size())).toString();
}
```

Still not using quesion though, so you could then change the method to a no-parameter argument.

Comment: Yep, there's a second `question` inside the for loop, but that's a separate variable that never escapes from the loop.

Comment: yep thats perfect:), works like it should be :) thank you, and everyone for contribution. PS thank you to Emanuel Moecklin for link to codeconvension, i will surely read it :)!

Answer (score 0):

You never used 'quesion' in your Question method and so it will return null, you should update it your method based on your requirement.

Your program violates N number of java coding practices like keeping meaningful method name,variable names etc.

Also your whole logic of getting a String from List is missing.